# Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am getting an error on installing the package using a recipe in Linux.

```
================================================================================[0m
    [31mError executing action `install` on resource 'package[libxslt]'[0m
    ================================================================================[0m

[0m    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed[0m
    ------------------------------------[0m
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
[0m    ---- Begin output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 ----
[0m    STDOUT: [option installonlypkgs] kernel kernel-bigmem installonlypkg(kernel-module) installonlypkg(vm) kernel-enterprise kernel-smp kernel-debug kernel-unsupported kernel-source kernel-devel kernel-PAE kernel-PAE-debug
[0m    STDERR: yum-dump Repository Error: failure: repodata/5c43262c2b560eb91f2874d3ef6e20536af2b9ec1421335130736b6d1e1a73a7-primary.sqlite.bz2 from pgdg93: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
[0m    ---- End output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 ----
[0m    Ran /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 returned 1[0m
```

I am using chef version 11.18.12

Can someone explain me the cause and solution?

Comment: `[Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.` Is not this enough? Have you tried to run yum by hand?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments `[Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.` is the real error from Yum, however Chef 11 is quite old and unsupported (and unsafe) so I recommend you try with something newer if possible. Barring that, it looks like your config for the `pgdg93` repo may need to be updated or the repo may be having server issues.